# How to implement automatic replacement of typos in Delphi2010

Tags: delphi, ide, plugins, delphi-2010, spell-checking

I am looking for a way to develop a plugin for Delphi 2010IDE and have yet to find any information on that topic, not even on how to get started.

What I want to accomplish is some kind of auto-spellchecker wich can be given a list of common typos (flase instead of false, .cerate instead of .create and the like) and replace them with the intended word.

Do you know of a tutorial on plugin development, or maybe an open source plugin which i could base my work on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GExperts has a CodeProofreader as one of it's plugins which would do what I think you want to do, it's also Open Source so if you do want to write your own that might be a good place to start.

Comment: +1 for CodeProofreader. I haven't had a compiler error on ";=" since :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Delphi's [Live Templates](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Live_Templates) for this and have common typos expand into the intended phrase.